# Lightweight encrypting for BLE advertising packets

Tags: sha-3, lightweight, blake2

I'm new to encryption and this is my first time working with it. I'm currently working on a home project which consists of the equipment in my garage to be attached with a BLE device which sends advertising packets to my TI Launchpad for keeping inventory. My question is how/what can I do to encrypt the advertisment packets so that when a third party sees these data, woudln't know whats happening. Clearly I'm not working with sensitive information but just a lightweight encryption is all I need as I know im working iwht limited space and power. Two things that I've found during research is Tiny-AES and BLAKE2 hash functions. For a beginner, what would you recommend I do in order to create a top layer security for my project. Any help/thoughts are welcome, Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography.SE. What do you mean by `woudln't know whats happening`?

Comment: Thank you for the welcome! Just in general as if a third party would be collecting advertisement packets data over time, they wouldn't be able to make use of an assumption of what's going on.

Comment: We assume that the adversaries know all about the system except the key. So, this is not an online system so that you can insert some encrypted data so that no one can see there is random data transmitting or data is transmitted at the moment. What you need indistinguishable encryption, IND-CPA should be enough like CBC and CTR mode. You may go to CCM mode that is designed for lower systems that can produce integrity and authentication together with confidentiality. You may also need some error correction since the medium can be noisy.

Comment: What are your thoughts on Tiny-AES. I've spent the last three hours looking at finding documentation on how I can implement these encryption techniques for advertisement packets but seem to find virtually nothing.

Comment: You did not found what? What did you exactly search for? Here a [Tiny AES C](https://github.com/kokke/tiny-AES-c) with 2.6K star.